# Jackson serializes Enum to NAME not value (XML) Java

Tags: java, jackson, xml-serialization

I have this Enum defined:

```
public enum OutputFormatEnum {
    PDF("pdf"),

    DOCX("docx"),

    XLSX("xlsx"),

    PPTX("pptx"),

    HTML("html"),

    PRN("prn"),

    CSV("csv"),

    RTF("rtf"),

    JPG("jpg"),

    PNG("png"),

    SVG("svg"),

    EPS("eps"),

    BMP("bmp"),

    GIF("gif"),

    TXT("txt");

    private String value;

    OutputFormatEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static OutputFormatEnum fromValue(String value) {
        for (OutputFormatEnum b : OutputFormatEnum.values())
            if (b.value.equals(value))
                return b;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
}
```

I have a model object that has a OutputFormatEnum variable called OutputFormat. When I set this variable to OutputFormatEnum.PDF, it is initially registered as "pdf" which is what it should be. When I then execute the following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream streamTemplate = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
xmlMapper.writeValue(streamTemplate, {model_object_with_enum_variable});
```

It sets the value of OutputFormat in streamTemplate to "PDF", where it should be "pdf" (the value of OutputFormatEnum.PDF). Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Your example code is incomplete. This is likely the difference between using the enum name, its `toString()` value or some other getter. It is not possible to tell what the issue is without seeing the code.

Comment: @Pieter12345 João Dias I added the full implementation. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@JsonValue` to the `getValue()` method so that this method is used by Jackson to serialize the instance:

```java
public enum OutputFormatEnum {
    PDF("pdf"),

    DOCX("docx"),

    XLSX("xlsx"),

    PPTX("pptx"),

    HTML("html"),

    PRN("prn"),

    CSV("csv"),

    RTF("rtf"),

    JPG("jpg"),

    PNG("png"),

    SVG("svg"),

    EPS("eps"),

    BMP("bmp"),

    GIF("gif"),

    TXT("txt");

    private String value;

    OutputFormatEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static OutputFormatEnum fromValue(String value) {
        for (OutputFormatEnum b : OutputFormatEnum.values())
            if (b.value.equals(value))
                return b;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
}
```

---

Given that you are serializing this to XML, you might need to use `@XmlValue` instead:

```java
public enum OutputFormatEnum {
    PDF("pdf"),

    DOCX("docx"),

    XLSX("xlsx"),

    PPTX("pptx"),

    HTML("html"),

    PRN("prn"),

    CSV("csv"),

    RTF("rtf"),

    JPG("jpg"),

    PNG("png"),

    SVG("svg"),

    EPS("eps"),

    BMP("bmp"),

    GIF("gif"),

    TXT("txt");

    private String value;

    OutputFormatEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static OutputFormatEnum fromValue(String value) {
        for (OutputFormatEnum b : OutputFormatEnum.values())
            if (b.value.equals(value))
                return b;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
}
```

In addition to this, you need to enable the support for the standard JAXB annotations as follows:

```java
xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```